# Exception when using scanner to read data

Tags: java

I am getting the below Exception when trying to run this.I am using a online compiler.Even tried using a nextLine() after reading the string but it did not work.

```
    Input:
    Enter the Customer Name:Roger Clinton
    Enter the Customer id:101
    Enter Credit Limit:10000


    Expected Output
    The Customer details are
    Customer Name: Roger Clinton
    Customer id: 101
    Credit Limit: 10000.00


    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

           Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 

           System.out.println("Enter the Customer Name:");
           String name=sc.nextLine();
           sc.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Enter the Customer id");
           int id=sc.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Enter Credit Limit:");
           double bal=sc.nextDouble();
           System.out.println("The Customer details are");
           System.out.println("Customer Name:"+name);
           System.out.println("Customer id:"+id);
           System.out.println ("Credit Limit: "+String.format("%.2f", bal));

        }
    }
```

I got the below Exception:
    Enter the Customer Name:
    Enter the Customer id
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)

Comment: the exception is thrown when you use next() so how would putting something _after_ that help?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. The code runs OK on my machine.

Comment: why are you making three scanners instead of using the first one?

Comment: some online ide doesn't support user input, check that your ide support it

Comment: There is a problem with your online IDE. It works on my machine in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Patrick Parker you were right I should have used only 1 scanner.I corrected and re executed similar problem persists.Not Sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the Credit Card details");
        System.out.println("Enter the expiry month :");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int exp=sc.nextInt();
        Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the card holder name :");
        String name = sc1.nextLine(); // ** i guess you had a typo here** 
        Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the credit balance :");
        float bal=sc2.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Credit Card Details");
        System.out.println("Expiry Month :"+exp);
        System.out.println("Name :"+name);
        System.out.println ("Credit Balance :"+String.format("%.2f", bal));

    }
}
```